# How to omit JavaScript and comments using nutch crawl?

Tags: nutch

I am a newbie at this, trying to use **[Nutch 1.2](http://nutch.apache.org/)** to fetch a site. I'm using only a Linux console to work with **Nutch** as I don't need anything else. My command looks like this 
`bin/nutch crawl urls -dir crawled -depth 3`

Where the folder *urls* is were I have my links and I do get the results to the folder *crawled*.
And when I would like to see the results I type:`bin/nutch readseg -dump crawled/segments/20110401113805 /home/nutch/dumpfiles`
This works very fine, but I get a lot of broken links.
Now, I do **not** want **Nutch** to follow JavaScript links, only regular links, could anyone give me a hint/help on how to do that?
I've tried to edit the *conf/crawl-urlfilter.txt* with no results. I might have typed wrong commands!

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

beware there are two different filter files, one for the one stop crawl command and the other for the step-by-step commands.
For the rest just build a regex that will match the urls you want to skip, add minus before and you shoulb de done.